# JSF Session Attribute isn't saved

Tags: jsf

We are doing a university project on JSF.
On login a function is called which validates the data of the user & then sets a session attribute, then redirects to Home, where we give out the Username `#{loginFrontend.username}` - it shows up right after the login. But when I click on another page and back on Home, the username disappeared.

```
@ManagedBean(name = "loginFrontend")
@SessionScoped
public class LoginFrontend implements Serializable{
    private String username;
    private String password;
    private Integer userid;
    private String role;

    /* Validating Stuff going on here*/

 FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
        HttpSession session = (HttpSession)context.getExternalContext().getSession(false);

        session.setAttribute("userid",userid);
        session.setAttribute("role",role);
```

Comment: What did you investigate? Did you check if the session is the same? And why if you are using a sessionScoped bean which contains these fields, do you ADDITIONALLY put variables in the session via a very old-school (unusual) way? I'd personally go to a different university

Comment: I don't know, I can't really find anything about that. I tried it without sessionscoped and with setting the Attributes as shown. But it also did not work.

Comment: To exclude the obvious, what package did you import the `@SessionScoped` annotation from? There are at least two possible candidates in Java EE API and only one of them is correct for a `@ManagedBean`. In any case, if accessing the `HttpSession` directly also doesn't work then it simply means that your webbrowser is (mis)configured to not maintain the session cookies. The server can't do much against it then.